# mongoDb deserializing the property of class issue

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0

i am trying to get data from mongodb using c# driver. my database structure look like this-

[image: Database structure]

My class looks like -

```
public class Elementtab
{
    public string  Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; } //new
    public string url { get; set; } // new
    public string owner { get; set; } //suaveid
    [BsonElement("date")]

    public DateTime date { get; set; } //1
       [BsonElement("captureStart")]
    public DateTime captureStart { get; set; } //new
    public Int32  checksum { get; set; } //new
    public Boolean approved { get; set; } //new
    public string comment { get; set; } //new
    public Boolean hasContent { get; set; } //new
    [BsonElement("clips")]
    public List<valuecon> clips { get; set; }
}
public class valuecon
{
    [BsonElement("html")]
    public string html { get; set; } //new


    [BsonElement("htmlTag")]
    public string htmlTag { get; set; } //new


    [BsonElement("src")]
    public string src { get; set; } //new
    [BsonElement("snapshot")]
    public string snapshot { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("range")]
    public string range { get; set; }//new

    [BsonElement("Type")]  //new+old
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("id")] //subelementid+new
    public string id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("size")]
    public Int32 size { get; set; }


    [BsonElement("box")]
    public List<box> box { get; set; }

}
```

It gives me exception as-

An error occurred while deserializing the clips property of class newdata+Elementtab: Expected element name to be '_t', not '3'. 
Please help me and tell me why this error occur and where i am doing wrong.

Comment: I would comment out one property at the time until you see which one fails

Comment: It's expecting a list[Array]. You have sub-documents.

Comment: i did't get you. where should i use list[Array] and how?